# How to use Css Media to differentiate high-res mobile in landscape mode from PC?

Tags: css, media-queries, landscape, 51degrees

I have a PC with a resolution of 1280x1024, and a smartphone Lumia 920 with a resolution of 1280x768 when used in landscape mode.

Can I use css `Media query` to make the difference between the 2 ? Because the text is rendered too small on the smartphone, and I want to use css to server a bigger font on it.

I have also investigated the option of `51degrees.mobi` which differentiates between a mobile and a PC, but I can not see how to use this library with css.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Thanks. @media only screen and (min-resolution: 97dpi) worked. Below is for PC, and beyond is for mobile. I was under the impression that the dpi was not correctly detected : http://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php gives 96 in both the PC and in the smartphone.

Answer (score -2):

your PC & MOBILE have the same width but different Height ! so you can specifiy Height like below 
for your PC

```
@media (height: 1024px){
/*put your CSS code here */
}
```

also for you mobile

```
@media (height: 768px){
/*put your CSS code here */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't have your browser maximised or if you have toolbars that make your viewport smaller.

Comment: Still, I think a PC can have a height of 768px

Comment: put mini-height into brace instead of height